# How Do I set an Image view resource randomly in android while extending the appwidget provider

Tags: android, random, widget

Hi I'm relatively new to android programming, and I need some help with setting up my widget, I'm stuck trying to set the image view resource randomly when the widget updates, I have tried

```
Random r = new Random();
int min = 001;
int max = 721;
String name = "national" + r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.source);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgwidg, pendingIntent);
views.setImageViewResource(id);
```

but it isn't accepting `getResources()` or `getIdentifier()`

what do I do?

Edit:
I'm also pretty sure it won't like 001 so how can i format the number to be 3 digits?

Edit 2: (Solved) With thanks to @ci_ and @blipinsk

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context,appWidgetManager,appWidgetIds);
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    Log.i("ExampleWidget", "Updating widgets " + Arrays.asList(appWidgetIds));



    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this
    // provider
    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int min = 1;
        int max = 721;
        int id3 = r.nextInt(max)+min;
        int id2 = id3 - 1;
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        String[] title = res.getStringArray(R.array.nationaltitles);
        String name = "national" + String.format("%03d",id3);
        int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        if (id == id){
            id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
            id2 = id3 - 1;
        }
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.source);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgwidg, pendingIntent);
        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgwidg, id);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv2,title[id2]);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

Comment: and you've got ~700 resources in your `drawable` directory called `nationalXYZ`?

Comment: yep i do well a few more but yes, they are really small though about 0.5 to 1 kb per file

Comment: If that code is inside `onUpdate()` you should be able to get your images with `context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`getResources()` is a method of `Context`. All the `AppWidgetProvider` [methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html) provide a `Context` as a parameter, so you can use that to call `getResources()` on.

To format an integer to a particular width you can use [String.format()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...))

i.e. `String.format("%03d", r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min)`

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to change the beginning of your code to this:

```
int min = 1;
int max = 721;
String name = "national" + String.format("%03d", r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min);
```

this will format your integers to match the `XYZ` format (three digits with leading zeros if needed).